# "when can't we?" or "when we can't?"

Tags: word-order, questions

Are the following questions grammatically correct?

> - When can we use CSS3 to round corners and when **can't we**?
> - When can we use CSS3 to round corners and when **we can't**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Of the two sentences, only the first is grammatically correct, "...and when can't we." The second form would be correct in a sentence like -

> I'd like to know when we can use CSS3 to round corners and when we can't

In this example, note the usage of "when we can" as opposed to "when can we."